# How download attachments from secondary outlook email by Python?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I need download attachment from outlook, but not from my outlook.

I need it from secondary group address (like `FiTeam@email.com` with pass = asdf).

Right now I have working script that downloading it from my own outlook address.

```
    import os


path = os.path.expanduser("D:\DownloadingEmail\\replenishment")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items


def saveattachemnts(subject):
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject.startswith(subject):
            # body_content = message.body
            attachments = message.Attachments
            attachment = attachments.Item(1)
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))
                if message.Subject == subject and message.Unread:
                    message.Unread = False
                continue

saveattachemnts('Replenishment')
```

How can I modify it to download the attachment from inbox in `FiTeam@email.com?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To access the shared `inbox` try the following*

> ```
> inbox = outlook.Folders["FiTeam@email.com"].Folders["Inbox"]
> ```

*also you should fix `("D:\DownloadingEmail\\replenishment")` to `("D:\\DownloadingEmail\\replenishment")`*

---

*`SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)` should be `SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment.FileName)`*

---

*`message.Unread = False` to `message.UnRead`*

---

*see my example code below-*

```
import os
import win32com.client
path = os.path.expanduser("D:\\DownloadingEmail\\replenishment")
print(path)
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders["FiTeam@email.com"].Folders["Inbox"]
messages = inbox.Items


def save_attachments(subject):
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject.startswith(subject):

            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment.FileName)))
                if message.UnRead:
                    message.UnRead = False
                continue


save_attachments('Replenishment')
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `outlook.CreateRecipient("FiTeam@email.com")`, then pass the returned `Recipient` object to `outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder()`