# Shared Mailbox in Outlook error in pywin32

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I try to get access of a shared mailboy in my outlook with this:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
groupMail = outlook.Folders.Item('example@company.com')
inbox = groupMail.Folder.Item('Inbox')
msg = inbox.Items
msgs = msg.GetLast()
```

I hoped it gaves my the last message but it gaves me this error:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Der versuchte Vorgang konnte nicht ausgeführt werden. Ein Objekt wurde nicht gefunden.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048041/4539709

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Inbox folder). The following VBA sample code shows how to use that method:

```vb
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is `MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`, which means the folder with the given name does not exist.

You can

1. Make sure the name is right - are you sure you specify the right name? Is the store named using the SMTP address or it is just a name?
2. Use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(..., olFolderInbox)` instead